# unresolved external symbol compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I frequently have this problem when I try a new library. This time I work with PointGrey Camera and try to use its API libraries (some dll, lib, header files). Mostly, problems were fixed by configuring the SDK (I'm using VS2008) Tools/Options/VC++ Directories/include files(/library files)(/executable files),
I also tried with project configuration: 
+ project properties/linker/input/additional dependencies
+ project properties/linker/General/Additional Library Directories

This time, with all this, I still have the error.

Is there a general method to deal with this problem?

do I need to understand this diagnosis from VS2008?

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__flycaptureGetPacketInfo referenced in function "enum FlyCaptureError __cdecl initializeStandardEventSizes(void *,struct FlyCaptureImageEvent * const)" (?initializeStandardEventSizes@@YA?AW4FlyCaptureError@@PAXQAUFlyCaptureImageEvent@@@Z)  main_2.obj  test
```

does using analysis tool such as Dependencies Walker ensure to solve these problems well??

Comment: Please clarify a bit: did you add all required library files to project settings (something like Link->Object/library modules; dunno how it is done exactly in VS2008) or you just added library __directories__ to the configuration?

Comment: I tried both ways: added the API libs have 2 lib file *.lib in the configuration setting (also added directory); second, I copy all the static libs  & DLLs of the API to working folder. Both didn't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved lately. I installed the incompatible library of PointGrey. That's why it didn't work. But this says something between "incompatible library" and "unresolved exertal symbol error"

Comment: in addition, sometimes it's really hard to choose the correct API library to install. I use Win7 x64 but the installation of PointGrey x64 never works. Now, it works so smoothly with PointGrey SDK x86. Not just that, I have to install the newest SDK v2.3. the others don't work. Whereas, according to installation instruction on the PointGrey website, any of them works just fine with win7 and VS2008. Sooo.... confusing and troublesome!!

Answer (score 1):

This message says that you used a symbol (a function or a variable) in your code. This symbol was probably declared somewhere (most likely in a header file you included in your code) otherwise there would have been a compilation error. When the linker searched for the symbol (in both your object files and the lib files you instructed it to look in) it couldn't find it.

That usually happens because you forgot to let the linker know about a lib you want it to search in.

Most libraries come with a set of instruction that is supposed to help you set up everything correctly and avoid running into these problems.

Comment: as I said clearly in the question, I've done what I normally did with other API libs. For example, OpenCV libraries, but it still didn't work. I'm using Point Grey camera API now and there aren't many libraries, 2 *.lib and a folder of *.dll. what goes wrong? and how to fix it

Comment: @SonLe What you normally do may seem normal to you, but I have no idea what you did and if it makes any sense to do it or not. The specific library you're using now (and not any other library you used in the past) probably comes with instructions how to use it.

Comment: please read my original question if you do care. I wrote everything there. I also emphasized this in the last comment

Comment: @SonLe So you did not follow the instructions that come with the library, you just decided to do something else. It is pretty likely it would't work.

Comment: this problem has been solved lately. I installed the incompatible library of PointGrey. That's why it didn't work. But this says something between "incompatible library" and "unresolved exertal symbol error"